# How do I render a UIView without blocking the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a view that draws many many `UIBezierPath`s, and drawing them takes quite a long time (1.34 seconds according to Instruments). Currently, the app behaves like this: I press a button to draw the view, the app freezes for 1.34 seconds, and then the view is shown. I want to show a loading indicator while the view is drawing and keep the rest of the app responsive. This would involve drawing the view in a background dispatch queue, but I don't know how to do that.

MCVE:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // note that this takes longer to draw than my actual view
        UIColor.label.setStroke()
        for _ in 0...300 {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            // obviously I won't be drawing random paths in the real app, but the actual shapes of the paths don't matter
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<bounds.width), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<bounds.height)))
            for _ in 0...200 {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<bounds.width), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<bounds.height)))
            }
            path.close()
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@IBAction func click() {
    let myView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

I used instruments to try to find out which part of the code is taking the longest to run. To my surprise, it is not the double for loop. It's not even my code. It seems to be a CoreGraphics function called `aa_render`:

[image]

I tried to put the code in a background dispatch queue, but as expected, it didn't work because you can't call UI APIs in a background thread:

```
var dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "viewDrawer")
@IBAction private func click() {
    dispatchQueue.async {
        let myView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

I noticed that there is a [`canDrawConcurrently`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483425-candrawconcurrently) in macOS, but it doesn't seem to be available on iOS.

How can I draw the view in the background?

---

**Why am I drawing so many paths?**

I am actually drawing a map using GeoJSON. The GeoJSON file is extremely detailed. The file size is a whopping 5MB. I actually don't need it to be that detailed... I just can't find a less detailed map  The map contains about 300 regions that the user can colour. Note that I'm fine with it taking a long time to draw. I just want to do it in the background.

**Doesn't reading the JSON file also take a long time?**

Yes, 130ms according to instruments, which is relatively short if you compare it to the time drawing the view, which is why I focused on the latter.

Comment: Miscellany of points: * Drawing paths directly is much faster than drawing bezier paths. * Drawing itself , e.g. into a graphics context, can be done in the background; it's the drawing into the view that must be done on the main thread. So you could drawing into an image context and draw the image. * Note that you can draw into a _layer_ concurrently in iOS.